# XML - proper way to escape string

Tags: php, ios, iphone, xml, xml-parsing

I just want to add in  tag any string.

I am using this code to escape string:

```
$name = $this->_dom->createElement('name', htmlspecialchars($userName, ENT_COMPAT,'utf-8'));
$item->appendChild($name);
```

I got a problem, one of my users put to name field some specific symbols, and whole xml feed become broken. How i must escaping string?

Thank for help and sorry for my poor English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
$title = $this->_dom->createElement('title',
    htmlspecialchars($playlist->getTitle(), 
    ENT_DISALLOWED, 'utf-8')
);
```

And when you output xml, you must strip � ([REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFFF0.pdf)) see [this](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) related link about ENT_DISALLOWED like:

```
echo str_replace('�', '', $this->_dom->saveXML());
```

This way allows us to display any string with html entities and/or special chars.

Answer (score 2):

I think adding the xml node's value by using createTextNode instead of passing it as a parameter to createElement may solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I will test it and write here results.

Comment: i will check this issue on monday. Don't worry, i will check your answer "accepted". A lot of thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but it's more that I wanted to make sure I helped. :)